# Recursively split a list into two parts

Tags: python, recursion

The question is how to make this into a recursive function.

> Split a list into two parts. `even` contains the even-indexed elements, `odd` contains the odd-indexed elements. Order of even and odd is not significant.

```
 def split_alt(self):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Split a list into two parts. even contains the even indexed
    elements, odd contains the odd indexed elements.
    Order of even and odd is not significant.
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Postconditions:
        returns
        even - the even indexed elements of the list (List)
        odd - the odd indexed elements of the list (List)
        The list is empty.
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    even = List()
    odd = List()

    while self._front is not None:
        new_node = self._front
        self._front = self._front._next
        new_node._next = even._front
        even._front = new_node

        if self._front is not None:
            new_node = self._front
            self._front = self._front._next
            new_node._next = odd._front
            odd._front = new_node

    odd._count = self._count // 2
    even._count = self._count - odd._count
    self._count = 0
    return even, odd

    def split_alt(x):
     if not x:
       return []
     if x[0] % 2 == 0: #even
       return [x[0]] + split_alt(x[1:])
     else:
       return split_alt(x[1:]) + [x[0]]
```

This is what I have so far, I am not sure if it's right. Could someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Thus, if a list contained the values `'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'`, then `even` should contain `'a', 'c', 'e'` and `odd` should contain `'b', 'd'`.

Comment: If you aren't sure it's right, try running it and see what it outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although rofls' way is more Pythonic, it's not recursive.

```
def split_list(l):
    def sub(index, l, odd, even):
        try:
            if index % 2 == 0:
                even.append(l[index])
            else:
                odd.append(l[index])
        except IndexError: # we've reached the end of the list
            return odd, even
        return sub(index+1, l, odd, even) # recursive call by advancing the index
    return sub(0, l, [], []) # initial call to function
```

Answer (score 0):

code with only one function definition as follows. The main idea is: "cut" two elements from the list tail, then we get the sub list. Next, using the sub list to call list_split() recursively until the length of sub list reaching 1 (when length of original list is odd) or 0 (when length of original list is even).

```
def list_split (list, even, odd):
    if (len(list) % 2 == 0 and len(list) != 0):
        list_split (list[0:len(list) - 2], even, odd) #recursive call sublist
        odd.append(list[len(list) - 1])
        even.append(list[len(list) - 2])
    elif (len(list) % 2 == 1 and len(list) != 1):
        list_split (list[0:len(list) - 2], even, odd) #recursive call sublist
        even.append(list[len(list) - 1])
        odd.append(list[len(list) - 2])
    elif (len(list) == 1):
        even.append(list[0])
        return
    elif (len(list) == 0):
        return


# testing       
even = []
odd = []
list_split(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], even, odd)
print (odd)
print (even)
```

Comment: This is messy. The function is modifying variables that are declared outside of the function's scope.

Comment: Hi Chuck, based on your suggestions, I modified my code. Thank you. :)